# #define for unsigned long

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm attempting to use the `#define` directive to change all of "ulong" to "unsigned long".
Here is an example:

```
#define ulong unsigned long
ulong idCounter = 0;
```

Sadly, I think it ends up replacing ulong with "unsigned", rather than "unsigned long".  I tried "#define ulong (unsigned long)", but that didn't work either.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be.  What makes you think that?  And you should really be using a `typedef` instead of a `#define`.

Comment: I found what my problem was, it was a screwup somewhere else in the code (I changed a #define to a const, but forgot to add "=").  I'm kind of new to #defines, and was trying to understand them.  I'll just use typedef in the future.

Comment: That's precisely why you shouldn't be using `#define`s.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Better use a typedef. The reason your macro may fail is - it might not syntactically valid in some places. Consider:

```
double x = calc();
ulong v = ulong(x);
```

In this case, you get

```
unsigned long v = unsigned long(x);
```

This is not valid, because the cast form used is not compatible with the way you name the type (it has to consist of a simplier form, like a single word). Use a typedef:

```
typedef unsigned long ulong;
```

Comment: I understand now; didn't know there was a significant difference.  I'll refrain from using #define for substitution like that in the future.

Comment: Actually, I've never seen a cast done like that - I always do it as (ulong)x, which would work. But, if your syntax is valid (and I have no reason to doubt that, @litb), you raise a good point. +1.

Comment: @paxdiablo, well it's a C++ only feature, C doesn't have this cast. It's the only one i can think of that would break here - not sure whether there are other places. For other things, there are other places tho that affect C too: `#define intptr int*` would break for `intptr a, b;` for example. Thanks for your trust, mate :)

Comment: Then again, you can't write `ulong long` with a typedef. Not sure whether that proves the superiority of macros, or their inherent evil though ;)

Answer (score 9):

why don't you use just typedef?

```
typedef unsigned long ulong;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your macro works OK:

```
cpp ulong.c
```

gives

```
# 1 "ulong.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "ulong.c"

unsigned long idCounter = 0;
```

I originally assumed that you already had a typedef called `ulong` and were trying to override that with the preprocessor, but other people have a different take on it. If you actually want the `ulong`, you should use a typedef, as they said.